# How to fix the render error in my vscode or some Electron application like postman?

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

The following rendering problem is recently shown when VS Code is opened, and the similar Postman (also written in Electron) has this problem as well

[image: click here to see vscode render error image]

Comment: disable graphics acceleration, by setting or by command line argument

Comment: I have resolved the problem by following your steps. The reason I don't show the images directly is that my reputation is not good enough for me to show the images directly on this platform, but thanks anyway for your solution and problem editing